# "patients studied" or "studied patients"

Tags: adjectives, word-order

what is the correct word order in the example below;

> Among 425  'studied workers', the mean age was 32.

or

> Among 425 'workers studied', the mean age was 32.

Moreover, isn't it better saying it like this;
The mean age of 'workers studied' was 32.

Answer (score 1):

First sentence

> Among 425 '**studied workers**', the mean age was 32.

It shows that the survey includes 425 studied or learned workers (not other workers), while second sentence

> Among 425 '**workers studied**', the mean age was 32.

Shows that the survey includes 425 workers.

IMO, second sentence shows *no.of workers included* and first sentence shows their *attribute*.

Final sentence

> The mean age of workers studied was 32.

The sentence is correct and with this context, second sentence makes more sense than the first one.

Hope this would help.

Comment: *studied* in *studied workers* serves as an adjective. On the other hand, it, in *workers studied* it's a verb.